# Python Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm doing dictionaries in python now, and im trying to access the `profile.keys` and `profile.items` commands. All that happens though is something like `<dict_values object at 0x107fa50>` shows up. What should i do?

Comment: Can you post the code that is returning this?

Answer (score 19):

you have to call like this `profile.keys()` and `profile.items()`. They are methods.

> If you omit the brackets, you don't actually call the function.
>   Instead you get a reference to the function object.

```
>>> mydict = {'foo':'bar'}
>>> mydict.keys
<built-in method keys of dict object at 0x01982540>
>>> mydict.keys()
['foo']
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate over keys:

```
for x in profile.keys():
  print x
```

or values

```
for x in profile.values():
  print x
```

or key-value pairs:

```
for x, y in profile.items():
  print x, y
```

or just assign to a variable for later use

```
x = profile.items()
```

etc.